# Generating unique ID's for components and systems of an ECS and allowing serialization?

Tags: c++, templates, components, entity

I'm working with an entity component system where ID's are generated for components of the same class with a combination of templates that I'll post below. When attempting to load serialized data I'm having trouble figuring out how to re-create the exact order of ID generation for the components so that the correct components are associated with the correct ID's.

When a component derived class is created for the first time the code below generates a unique ID for components of that class.

```
typedef std::size_t TypeId;

template<typename BaseClass>
class ClassTypeId
{
public:
    template<typename BaseClass>
    static TypeId getTypeId()
    {
        static const TypeId id = nextTypeId++;
        return id;
    }

private:
    static std::atomic<TypeId> nextTypeId;
};

template <typename BaseClass>
std::atomic<TypeId> ClassTypeId<BaseClass>::nextTypeId{ 0 };

// Get a new ID if the components is new, or get the ID
// of the component of class T
template<class T>
TypeId ComponentTypeId()
{
    return ClassTypeId<Component>::getTypeId<T>();
}
```

**Is there a way of somehow storing the order in which these Id's are created for particular components and recreating/associating them with components of class T on loading the serialized data?** As  the components Id's will likely start to vary in order of creation as components are added to entities dynamically It's unlikely that creating them in the same order outside the ECS would be possible.

Or is there a better way to generated unique ID's for multiple base class types and multiple derived classes that allows for easy serialization?

Comment: can't you just use a UUID ?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with UUID's (meaning I just looked it up) but the component ID's need to start at or very close to zero and be sequential as they're stored and indexed / checked with bitsets. Probably not possible with UUID's?

Comment: you can use an hash map instead ( or use that hash map to associate to each uuid a zero-based, sequential index and vice-versa, if you really need it; ids will possibly change per run, uuid won't )

Comment: That's not a bad idea, but would require a pretty big overhaul of the ECS that I'm probably not comfortable doing :(. I'm thinking of possibly requiring each component to be registered on ECS init so that the order stays the same. But if there's some way to store class types so they can be dynamically registered on serialization that would be ideal.